# How are cookies getting identified through code?

Tags: cookies

I recently ran a `CCleaner` on my computer. In the report it had given to me it said: "XXXX amount of `tracking cookies`" have been `removed`".

1) I was wondering how can the code tell that something `is a cookie`?

2) How can the code tell what `type of cookie` that is?

Comment: CCleaner knows about the browsers and where and how they store their cookies.

Comment: I see, I had a feeling that this could be the case. But I'm curious regardless whether there is a way of doing it just by looking at the file or its contents.

Comment: Which file exactly? Chrome stores it's cookies in a sqlite file in its own app directory. If you got a file, it's probably easy to find out whether its a sqlite file and contains google chromes cookies or not. Don't know about the other browsers though.